# Filter array by content?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, filter, filtering

I'm trying to filter an array that is non-object based, and I need the filter to simply check each piece of the array for a specific string.

Say I have this array:

```
["http://mywebsite.com/search", "http://mywebsite.com/search", "http://yourwebsite.com/search"]
```

What I need to do is harvest the array in a way so that I get a new array that only contain those who start with `http://mywebsite.com` and not `http://yourwebsite.com`

In conclusion making this: `["http://mywebsite.com/search", "http://mywebsite.com/search", "http://yourwebsite.com/search"]`

into this `["http://mywebsite.com/search", "http://mywebsite.com/search"]`

Comment: So you want to filter an array... have you tried using the `.filter` method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can filter the array using `.filter()` and `.startsWith()` method of String.

As from Docs:

> The `startsWith()` method determines whether a string begins with the characters of a specified string, returning true or false as appropriate.

**Demo:**

```js
let data = ["http://mywebsite.com/search",
            "http://mywebsite.com/search",
            "http://yourwebsite.com/search"];

let result = data.filter(s => s.startsWith('http://mywebsite.com/'));

console.log(result);
```

As mentioned in your comment; if you wants to check multiple strings then you can try this:

```js
let data = ["http://mywebsite.com/search",
            "http://mywebsite.com/find",
            "http://yourwebsite.com/search",
            "http://yourwebsite.com/find"];

let strToMatch = ["http://mywebsite.com/search", "http://mywebsite.com/find"];

let result = data.filter(s1 => strToMatch.some(s2 => s2.startsWith(s1)));

console.log(result);
```

**Docs:**

- [`String.prototype.startsWith()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/startsWith)
- [`Array.prototype.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)
- [`Arrow Functions`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)

Comment: Thank you, this works well. I would just like to know also if it's possible to reverse this concept so that what i choose to filter is filtered OUT, because currently what I filter is the only thing that stays. So that what you suggested above would result in an array where http://mywebsite.com/ is excluded.

Comment: @user10083700 Yes, just return negated value from callback i.e `data.filter(s => !s.startsWith('http://mywebsite.com/'))`

Comment: Can I have multiple arguments in there? Something like this:arr.filter(s => s.startsWith('http://mywebsite.com/search, http://mywebsite.com/find'));

Comment: @user10083700 I've updated my answer. There is no native support for multipe strings in this method. You will have to use an array for this.

Answer (score 0):

Use Array filter() method
You can make a simple function and pass that array of string and check what you want in it exist or not

```
var yourString = ["http://mywebsite.com/search", "http://mywebsite.com/search", "http://yourwebsite.com/search"];

function specificString(yourString ) {
    return yourString === "http://mywebsite.com/search";
}
console.log(specificString(yourString));
```